# How to extract columns from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a bot that gives me a graph for the wanted stock. I use the `yfinance` API for this but the problem is that when I e.g. say `APPL.history` it gives me the following values for APPL stock: 'Open, Low, High, Close, Volume, Dividens' and i am only interested in the open price.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf


def stock_data(ticker='', period='', interval=''):
   ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker)
   ticker_history = ticker.history(period, interval)
   print(ticker_history)

def open_price(ticker, period='', interval=''):
    price = np.extract(open)
    print(price)

open_price('APPL','3mo','1wk')
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a ticker with `ticker = yf.Ticker('AAPL')` than `history_as_df = ticker.history()` will return a python dataframe.

Please review [10 minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html) to get familiar with pandas dataframes.

To only select the `Open` column do

```
history_as_df[['Open']]
```

To extract those values as a `numpy` array do

```
history_as_df[['Open']].values
```